# File Upload Site that lets you start downloading while the file is being uploaded

Tags: http, file-upload, download

I came across a website that allowed someone to start downloading a file that you've started uploading, even before you finished, one of these new start ups for file uploading.
Lost the url for it and can't remember, anybody know it by any chance?

For future reference:
The website url is http://ge.tt/
(Rediscovered by @romkyns)

Comment: It is possible, I have successfully done precisely this multiple times last month. Just because you haven't seen it yet doesn't mean it's impossible..

Comment: Certainly possible (you just need to tweak the HTTP server a bit), but off-topic for this site.

Comment: What's a good site for this question? I really need to figure out what that website was

Comment: @Roman: Are you sure it was a *website*? What you're describing is possible with BitTorrent and similar P2P ("file sharing") technologies, but can't be easily accomplished with HTTP (the technology used in websites).

Comment: It's called [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol)).

Comment: Yes it was a website, I started uploading a 100MB file and it gave me a link to it. I gave the link to my friend and he started downloading it right away. Granted it was kinda slow, but it was a fully working implementation none the less.

Comment: This is very possible indeed, and I have always been surprised why on earth it took this long for someone to actually do it. Try it, @leppie, at http://ge.tt. @Roman, is this the one you used?

Comment: @romkyns: WOW! That is F$CKIN AWESOME! Very cool, I wonder how they do it.... Well I stand corrected :)

Comment: @romkyns: YES! that's the website I was looking for, thanks! Except now i forget what I needed it for lol